# OpenBmc: how to deploy phosphor-webui to bmcweb

Tags: javascript, html, linux, openbmc

I could not find a solution how to deploy Web GUI related files (such as phosphor-webui or webui-vue) to OpenBmc web server Bmcweb.

Where should I copy web content to make it visible after booting Linux?

Or maybe I should first make some changes to web GUI files and build the OpenBmc image?

Thanks in advance,
Andrew

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.